# vscode open each process in its own terminal automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, mern, vscode-tasks

In vscode is it possible to run a stack with each process in its own terminal?

For example, I am running a MERN stack and at the moment I manually starting a mongod instance, then opening a new terminal and starting express, then I am opening a third terminal and starting a react application.

Is there a way where I can run the app (from scratch) and have each process start up in its own terminal automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by finding [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52331208)

Here is the link to my tasks.json file so you can use it for yourself :-)

https://gist.github.com/to-jk11/d539458c492405cd56a2747028029060